# look in string for alternative patterns with spaces and minus symbols

Tags: r, grepl

I need detecting certain patterns within a vector of strings.
I have multiple possibile variants on how a certain pattern is written down, so I use the [] together with |, like in "summari[z|s]e"
It all works fine except in this one case, when spaces and "-" are involved.
Those aren't even characters to be escaped so..
..What am I missing?

I have tried escaping with \

```r
a<-"..contested - cred.."
b<-"..contested -cred.."
ab<-c(a,b)
grepl("..contested -[| ]",ab)
```

[1]  TRUE FALSE

whereas I would expect a return TRUE for both a and b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[| ]` means either a vertical bar or a space.  What you want is either a space or nothing.  In that case `?` means 0 or 1 occurrence of the prior character.  Also note that dot is a meta-character so escape it.

```
grepl("^\\.\\.contested - ?cred\\.\\.$", ab)
## [1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We may need.  The `|` is a metacharacter for `OR`.  Inside the square brackets, it would be evalated literally instead of the `OR`. Also, we can use the characters to match inside `[]` without any `|`

```
grepl("\\.{2}contested [- ]",ab)
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

NOTE: `.` is also a metacharacter that matches any character.  So, it needs escape (`\\.`) to evaluate literally